# Getting empty array in javascript using array.push() method

Tags: javascript

I am trying to push data into array in this code

```
let eyesData = [];

const pushFaceData = (
    { rightEyeOpenProbability },
    i
  ) => {
    //Value is getting printed  in console but not getting pushed
    //console.log(rightEyeOpenProbability);
    eyesData.push(rightEyeOpenProbability);
   
  };

const renderFaces = () => {
    faces.map(pushFaceData);
  };

console.log(eyesData);
```

**faces** is stream of data that updates itself in every 100ms so **eyesData** array should also be getting populated on each 100ms but in console, eyesData is always getting printed with empty value.

```
Array[]
Array[]
.
.
```

Comment: *"faces is stream of data"* What does that mean? It looks like an array, given you're calling `map` on it. (That should be `forEach`, btw; you're not *mapping* anything.)

Comment: Your code shows you creating the `eyesData` variable, assigning `[]` to it, and then logging it, with no intervening call to `renderFaces` or `pushFaceData`. That's why it's empty. I suspect there's more to it in your real code, but we can only work with what you show us. Please update your question with a [mcve] demonstrating the problem, ideally a **runnable** one using Stack Snippets (the `[<>]` toolbar button); [here's how to do one](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/).

Comment: @T.J.Crowder agree with the `map()` thing, but loop should run right. And data should be pushed into `eyesData`. Right?

Comment: `if(!eyesData){eyesData=[]}eyesData.push(rightEyeOpenProbability);`

Comment: @TusharShahi - Not with the code above. It never calls `renderFaces`, so it never calls `pushFaceData`. But yes, if `renderFaces` were called, it would work (That's why I think there's more to it and hope the OP provides that [mcve], so we can help.). It's just misleading semantically and creates and throws away an unnecessary array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `rightEyeOpenProbability` is printing to the console, then there is no reason your code should be failing...

You are probably changing `eyesData` somewhere. For example, if you made a typo when checking its length, you could be erasing it:

```js
if( eyesData.length = 0 ) { ... } //this line would erase eyesData[]'s contents
```